# Users post to twitter from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter, passwords

I've a property website where user can add property after twitter logged in. 
Now I want to post update on twitter about property on his/her twitter page. How its posible?
I've setuped twitter aap. My site in wordpress so I can not trace users password. What is solution for this can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tools/)?